# In Android, how to check if an image picked from gallery has been marked as favourite by the user?

Tags: android, kotlin

My project requires me to display all images from the gallery that have been marked as favourite (in the gallery) by the user.

I have tried the following code and then used contentResolver to query through all images in the MediaStore.

```
        val projection =
        arrayOf(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_FAVORITE,
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.IS_DOWNLOAD,
        )

        val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, "$orderBy DESC")
```

This works perfectly on SDK above 30. But the IS_FAVORITE MediaColumn is not supported on lower SDKs.

Is there any way to achieve this in SDK 23?

Answer (score 0):

The Android API added `IS_FAVORITE` in API level 30. Only those devices that have API 30 or above will support this feature older devices like those running on 23 will not be able to do so. Also there is no way of providing this as backward compatibility. You can check official documents [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#IS_FAVORITE).

Comment: IS_FAVORITE always gives value 0. Seems it's not working. Are you able to get right values for it?

Comment: @hov.terteryan can you elaborate a bit more ?